# Laravel interface dependency inject

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, interface, bind

I have a interface dependency inject Question,
the error message look like can`t catch the class,
have any ideal?

Error Message:

```
FatalThrowableError in UserController.php line 27:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App' not found
```

My folder path :

[image]

UserController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Domain\Services\Social\SocialService;
use Domain\Services\Social\SocialInterface;
use Domain\Services\Social\Facebook;

class UserController extends Controller
{
  public function fb(Request $request)
  {
    App::bind(SocialInterface::class, Facebook::class);
    $target = App::make(SocialService::class);
    return $target ->getCallbackData($request);
  }
}
```

SocialService.php

```
namespace Domain\Services\Social;

class SocialService
{
    public function getCallbackData(SocialInterface $social,$request)
  {
      return $social->getCallbackData($request);
  }
}
```

Facebook.php

```
namespace Domain\Services\Social;

class Facebook implements SocialInterface
{

  public function getCallbackData($request)
  {
     //Somethig inside...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public function fb(Request $request)
  {
    \App::bind(SocialInterface::class, Facebook::class);
    $target = \App::make(SocialService::class);
    return $target ->getCallbackData($request);
  }
```

Try it with backslash.

Comment: thanks, it works!
but, why should need to add a slash fornt it?

Comment: Because you want to call an object in namespace `App`, however in your controller file you defined namespace `App\Http\Controllers`, so Laravel tries to load an object in this namespace.